# stacked Modals or some other alternative jquery popup modals

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any alternative to multiple modals. I need multiple instances of modals.

When clicked on Open modal in the main page open a modal (Modal-A) which is a form, and a link  on Modal-A to open up another modal (Modal-B).

Modal-B will also be a form,When Modal-B is closed some values in Modal-A needs to be updated,
and when Modal-A is closed the main page needs to be updated.

Any work around to get it done, i cant get multiples modal working.

I am using BS3

Comment: Bootstrap's modals don't support stacking. There are some third-party plugins that implement it though.

Comment: Can you please help me out with some , Modal-A needs to be updated when Modal-B is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/svYtb33XTs

*I explain* :

*Open modal, open second modal, type something in input, close the modal (cross or cancel, I didn't code the save changes), the button of first modal is updated...*

**JS**

```
$('#myModal1').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
    $('a').html(  $('#myModal1 input').val()        );
});
```

**HTML** :

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…
      <a href="#myModal1" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>      
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Type something here and close modal.... (cancel or close)</p>
      <input>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm.. What if the second modal's markup is embedded within first modal? Then the `show.bs.modal`, `shown.bs.modal`, `hide.bs.modal`, `hidden.bs.modal` events of inner modal will bubble up to parent modal, won't they? If you are wondering about a case where such thing is needed, then consider a  case where the entire content of primary modal (and its relevant secondary modal) is being loaded with jquery `.load()`